# Foudation XY-Grid - overrule container width

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using the new Foundation XY-grid on a new project. The site has a max-width of 1000px for the grid-container.
All is well.

But, i now need to make a new component for the site using the Accordion component from Foundation. No problem there either.
The problem, starts when, the background, of the open accordion element, needs to be, another bg-color, than that of the parent element (edge-to-edge).
This would not be a problem, if it was not for the fact, that i needs to fill the entire width of the page - the background color that is.
The content itself, still has a max-width of 1000px.

This is the standard markup:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
      <div class="large-12 cell">
            <ul class="accordion" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed="true">
                <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
                        <a href="#deeplink1" class="accordion-title">Accordion header</a>
                        <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content id="deeplink1">
                            Accordion content
                        </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above works as expected, and has the same bg color as the `<body>` - all is good.

But, there is a variation, of the above, where the background color, differs from the `<body>` bg-color.
To do this, i simply wrap the `grid-container`, in a callout, like so

```
<div class="secondary callout">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
            <!-- accordion markup -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This also works as expected.

The problems starts, when i open an accordion item. 
The background-color, of the accordion item, needs to have the background-color from the `<body>` (or at least, not the same as the one from 'secondary callout').
But, how do I achieve this, in the best possible way?

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WXEMyp

Wanted output: [image]

Comment: Can you provide working code...?

Comment: @ankitapatel sure thing - i updated my post with a Codepen link

Comment: Now can you provide any screenshot  how do you want output..?

Comment: @ankitapatel Done. Was my post that unclear? :-)

Comment: So, the CodePen link points to an example of the *intended result*? I get the impression it does since it looks identicle to the embedded image ("Wanted output"). If that is the case, having a working example of the code with existing issues, that we can troubleshoot and debug, would be more helpful - a MVCE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError No, the CodePen contains my current, not working code. The reason maybe, that you see it, as my wanted outut, is because of your screen resolution? On wider resolutions, the green background will apear, as my example above :-)